# The probabilities (PMF) of a Zipf Random Variable Does not Add to 1

Tags: probability

[PIC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4brD.jpg)

Graphically, why do their total probability not add to 1?  Their PMF should add to 1. This is a distribution of a Zipf Random Variable Variable X

$$
p_X(k)={1\over c_Lk}
$$
for $k=1,2\dots ,L$
where

$$
c_L=\sum^L_{j=1} {1\over j}
$$
Then
$$
P[X>k]=1-P[X≤k]
$$

This last equations corresponds to the value of 1 at $X≤k=1$ !

Comment: It’s not entirely clear what this is charting, but the left-most $k$ value is $1,$ and there are no values charted on that point. Without knowing more about the source of the chart - Where does it come from? What is it trying to show? - it is hard to say more. Since the left-most points are $P(X>2),$ this presumably means $P(X\leq 2)>0.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of the function is $P(X>k)$ as indicated on the left side of the graph. So the function is not a PMF, which it would be only if the value was $P(X=k)$.

Comment: This is one of my most stupidest mistake. The night must me seeping through my brain. I've been cramming all of these within this day